# How can i make customized template for the front end by overriding the default one?

Tags: pyrocms

I am new to **Pyrocms** and reading the documentation I could not change fix my problem. I need my own template to be incorporated that is I want to change the default one provided. How can I do that. I really need a help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into:

```
system/cms/themes/default/
```

This is the folder where you can find the default template of pyrocms. There you will see folders like "views, css, js, img" etc.

You can start by modifying views/layouts/default.html and views/partials/ folder.

Ofcourse if you need to change css and/or js you need to modify them too.

By the way this is the official pyrocms documentation for editing themes:
http://www.pyrocms.com/docs/manuals/designers

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the link. The page in the link does not exists anymore. So is there any other link for the documentation? If yes i will be very very thankful.

Comment: this is for the new version 2.0: http://www.pyrocms.com/docs/2.0/manuals/designers/create-a-custom-theme and this is for the 1.3 one: http://www.pyrocms.com/docs/1.3/manuals/designers/create-a-custom-theme . Hope it helps